# How to use filter on grid except on empty records (ExtJS 6.5.3)

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, grid, extjs6

I have a grid with some records and a working filter if I type something in a textfield. But I also have records which are empty in each cell. Those records should still be shown even if I use a filter. Right now those records get also filtered out.

Comment: How do you use filtering? By `filterFn`? Or by `property`,`operator` and `value` ?

Comment: I am using ```property```, ```operator``` and ```value``` for filtering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use filterFn on your own.

Suppose - the filtered param is `age` which can be `null` or empty string.

```
var ageFilterFn = new Ext.util.Filter({
    filterFn: function(item) {
        return Ext.isEmpty(item.age) || item.age < 42;
    }
});
```

instead of :

```
var ageFilter = new Ext.util.Filter({
    property: 'age',
    value: 42,
    operator: '<'
});
```